# List of Asymmetric Animals

Tags: zoology, literature, species, morphology

The (male) **[Fiddler Crab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_crab)** is a famous example of an animal whose morphology exhibits **neither mirror nor radial symmetry**:

[image]
([Image source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fiddler_crab_anatomy-en.svg))

[List of animals featuring external asymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animals_featuring_external_asymmetry) is a Wikipedia article showcasing a few more animals with this property.

**Is there a *comprehensive* list of all such animals that have been described?**

Comment: Many(all?) sponges are asymmetrical.

Comment: I don't think that there is a list yet for all but I could probably help you with a few if that is ok.

Comment: Any that are not on the Wikipedia list would already be helpful :)

Comment: I am asymmetrical. My right hand is bigger than my left. :)

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page called ["list of animals featuring external asymmetry"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animals_featuring_external_asymmetry)

Answer (score 1):

1) [Pareas iwasakii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasaki's_snail-eater) has asymmetric mandibles.  A few more examples of asymmetric snakes ([reference](http://snakesarelong.blogspot.in/2012/04/asymmetrical-snakes.html))

[image]

Pareas iwasakii skull

2) Camels have an asymmetric penis ([reference](https://science.naturalis.nl/en/research/character-evolution/left-right-asymmetry/))

3) You could find quite a few in this article titled [Animal asymmetry](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982209009269)

Hope that helps. I am sure there are more but these are some I could find.