# Animals with substantial five-fold symmetry besides starfish? Any land animals?

Tags: evolution, anatomy, movement

Animals with four, six and eight legs are widespread while the concept of seven legs (fictitious Heptapods) are the makings of amazing scifi [short stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Your_Life) and blockbuster movies.

Are starfish the only types of animals currently (or ever) with five mostly equal sized appendages and substantial five-fold symmetry? Are there theories why five is unusual on land but common in the sea?

**update:** There is an interesting subtlety here. [This answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/39256/27918) points out that a sea star's legs are the little things under the five appendages, so I've adjusted the question to address instead five-fold symmetry and five appendages.

---

**below:** "Ophiopetra lithographica from the Lower Hienheim Beds (Lower Tithonian,Upper Jurassic) near Regensburg, Germany" from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ophiopetra_lithographica_aboral_larger_010813.jpg).

[image]

**below:** "A green brittle star - Ophiarachna incrassata" from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Greenbrittlestar.jpg).

[image]

**below:** "Une ophiure superbe (Ophiolepis superba) à la Réunion." from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ophiolepis_superba_R%C3%A9union.jpg).

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you will find it very interesting if you knew that actually there is a land animal with five limbs. If you are interested check [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn25829-zoologger-meet-the-only-animal-with-five-legs/) . I didn't want to post it as an answer because I thought it does not fully answers your question ;) . I forgot to mention that the land-animal I mentioned doesn't show symmetry to the fifth "limb".

Comment: @The_Mad_Fish I was a little hesitant to click your link until I saw it was the NewScientist. I clicked and then a big Aha! yep, well done :)

Comment: hahaha I hope that I covered you lol ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many (if not most) of the [**Echinoderms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinoderm) (to which starfish belong as well) have five-fold symmetry, such as many **sea liliy** ([Crinoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crinoid)) and **sea urchin** ([Echinodea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_urchin)) species.

**Five-fold symmetrical sea lilly:**

[image]

**Sand dollar (type of sea urchin):**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add that they are, however, **Bilaterians* (as opposed to Radiata), as their larvae, representing the ancestral state in the group, have bilateral symmetry.

Comment: I should have recalled sand dollars, thanks. OK so there are diverse members of an entire phylum, that's great! [Echinoderms are also the largest phylum that has no freshwater or terrestrial (land-based) representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinoderm#Ecology) so that settles it.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge that's an interesting feat.